# Protein PTM site prediction

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins

Is there any in silico analysis method to predict post-translational modification sites on a given protein?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually a lot of these sites available, I have used some of the one listed below. Additionally there are some huge list of other services available in this field from ExPASy, you can find it [here](http://www.expasy.org/proteomics) and the Center for Biological Sequence Analysis, which can be found [here](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/researchgroups/PTM.php).

- [ExPASy - FindMod](http://web.expasy.org/findmod/)
- [The Eukaryote Linear Motif resource for Functional Sites in Proteins](http://elm.eu.org/)
- [Phosida](http://www.phosida.com/)